# send information from a js variable to python

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I need to send an object that contains a variable in js, the idea is to be able to send that information to python (I use django) and capture that info to be able to perform the validations that I need from the backend (python) and not from js, how can I do it ?

code ajax:

function CapturarDatosOrden() {

```
$.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'action': 'prueba',
    },
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);

        $(".loader").fadeIn('fast');

    },
    dataType: 'json',

    complete: function (jqXHR) {
        // boton.disabled = false;           
        $('.loader').fadeOut('fast');
        var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },
}).done(function (data) {
    // alert('entro al primer ajax para comparar el tipo de orden y su tecnologia')

    var info = data.find(data => data.id__ordenes == idOrden);
```

the "info" variable has the object I need to capture in python, the object is something like this:

{ id__ordenes: "219661981", fk_ot__tipo_orden: "4", fk_bss__contratos: "3257733", otciudad: "1", otdireccion: "----", fk_ot__cc: "1", open_orden: "42588165", instalador: "4320", fk_contratistas__equipos_vendedores: "1", fk_ot__causales: "88" }

how can i do it?

Comment: See that `data` object in the JS? It seems to me like you need to add `info: info` as an entry in that object

Comment: @JacobIRR yes, the var "info" has the object , so i want to send that result to python, 'cause i need to make some conditionals with the data into the object but in python , not in the js :L

Comment: Can you share your django code?

Comment: Probably you want `JSON.stringify` on JS side and `json.loads` in python? (`json` from standard library)